# Can you spot the problem with this REGEX statement?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pycharm

Im running .txt files through a `for` loop which should slice out keywords and `.append` them into lists. For some reason my REGEX statements are returning really odd results.

My first statement which iterates through the full filenames and slices out the keyword works well.

```py
# Creates a workflow list of file names within target directory for further iteration
stack = os.listdir(
  "/Users/me/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries"
)

# declares list, to be filled, and their associated regular expression,       to be used,
# in the primary loop
names = []
name_pattern = r"-\s(.*)\.txt"

# PRIMARY LOOP
for entry in stack:
  if entry == ".DS_Store":
    continue

# extraction of country name from file name into `names` list
  name_match = re.search(name_pattern, entry)
  name = name_match.group(1)
  names.append(name)
```

This works fine and creates the list that I expect

However, once I move on to a similar process with the actual contents of files, it no longer works.

```
religions = []
reli_pattern = r"religion\s=\s(.+)."

# PRIMARY LOOP
for entry in stack:
  if entry == ".DS_Store":
    continue
# opens and reads file within `contents` variable
  file_path = (
  "/Users/me/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries" + "/" + entry
  )
  selection = open(file_path, "rb")
  contents = str(selection.read())

# extraction of religion type and placement into `religions` list
  reli_match = re.search(reli_pattern, contents)
  religion = reli_match.group(1)
  religions.append(religion)
```

The results should be something like: `"therevada", "catholic", "sunni"` etc.
Instead i'm getting seemingly random pieces of text from the document which have nothing to do with my `REGEX` like ruler names and stat values that do not contain the word `"religion"`
To try and figure this out I isolated some of the code in the following way:

```py
contents = "religion = catholic"
reli_pattern = r"religion\s=\s(.*)\s"

reli_match = re.search(reli_pattern, contents)

print(reli_match)
```

And `None` is printed to the console so I am assuming the problem is with my `REGEX`. What silly mistake am I making which is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression (`religion\s=\s(.*)\s`) requires that there be a trailing whitespace (the last `\s` there).  Since your string doesn't have one, it doesn't find anything when searching thus `re.search` returns `None`.

You should either:

1. Change your regex to be `r"religion\s=\s(.*)"` or
2. Change the string you're searching to have a trailing whitespace (i.e `'religion = catholic'` to `'religion = catholic '`)